# Geth - Check balance on --light mode

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, cli

I am running a lightmode geth daemon, and I want to check the balance of my daemon. I read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25177/why-do-i-never-see-eth-blocknumber-nor-eth-coinbase-on-light-sync-testnet) answer, which says that I cannot use the command that I am currently using, as it requires support for `eth.coinbase`

`geth --exec "web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), 'ether')" attach`

Geth synced in lightmode doesn't support use of `eth.coinbase`. What command can I use? Do I have to run a `--syncmode=fast` or standard node instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the first account is your addreess you can use

```
geth --exec "web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]), 'ether')" attach
```

For example you can ask for an arbitrary address replacing `eth.coinbase` with such address

```
geth --exec "web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance('0xFBb1b73C4f0BDa4f67dcA266ce6Ef42f520fBB98'), 'ether')" attach
```

Comment: Well damn, now I feel stupid. Thanks for your answer